# Is there any way to adjust the Alertify drop down and exit of the alerts?

Tags: alertify

Currently Alertify drops down the alert so that it bounces and comes back up a bit.  Is there a way to just have it slide down?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one had any answers here so I finally dug it out myself.

Alertify uses CSS3 transitions to show and hide its dialogs. 
As soon as the class is assigned the dialog bounces onto the screen:

```
elDialog.className = "alertify alertify-" + type + " " + css;
```

The classes are defined in alertify.core.css:

[image]

To get rid of the bounce I just replaced the cubic-bezier definitions:

[image]